# Excel Print Worksheets by Name

Tags: vba, excel, printing, worksheet

I've got an Excel 2007 Spreadsheet and I'd like to write a VBA procedure to print particular worksheets by name. How do I do this?

For example, 
I'd like to print `"FirstSheet","ThirdSheet",` and `"FourthSheet"` but not `"SecondSheet".`

Answer (score 7):

If you know the sheet name simply call the `PrintOut` function like this:

```
Sheets("Name").PrintOut
```

For small amounts of sheets it is quite more easy by this way!

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to the following should work:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If (sh.Name = "Sheet1") Then
           sh.PrintOut
        End If
Next sh
```

Comment: Can this be done in a batch? e.g. Can I print multiple sheets out in a single print job?

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub PrintByName(Names As Variant)

  Dim s As Worksheet
  Dim i As Integer

  If IsArray(Names) Then
    For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      For i = 0 To UBound(Names)
        If StrComp(s.Name, Names(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
          s.PrintOut
        End If
      Next i
    Next s
  End If

End Sub
```

Call like:

```
PrintByName Array("FirstSheet", "ThirdSheet", "FourthSheet")
```

The nested loop is not optimal, in regards to runtime performance. With the limited number of sheets an Excel workbook can contain, I think this is negligible. However, using a `Collection` to contain the desired sheet names instead of an `Array` would be better.

Comment: Do you think accusing *and* insulting people the same time is helpful in any way?

Comment: Sorry if I offended your fragile ego.

Comment: I don't think that it's my ego that is being fragile here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to loop to do this, one line of code will suffice:

```
Sheets(Array("FirstSheet", "ThirdSheet", "FourthSheet")).PrintOut Copies:=1
```